# "Also..." interjection in Japanese; appending an additional request or afterthought

Tags: translation, words, expressions, questions

In Japanese, how would one go about appending an additional request or afterthought?

For example:

> 1: お水【みず】をお願【ねが】いします。

"Water please."

> 2: あっ、（・・・）、氷【こおり】を入【い】れていただけませんか。

"..Ah **also**, could you add ice (to that)?" / "Additionally, could you add ice (to that)?"

More specifically, what would be the most natural way of filling in （・・・）? The closest word I know of would be それから, though I feel this word may be incorrect in this situation.

**Also**, is there a more natural way of phrasing the example sentences?

Comment: @jhenn Ah I see. Perhaps it's just my English. :P Regarding the second "also" though, I suppose それから would work?

Comment: That's fine in many situations and would be understood fine.  It just sounds more like you are going to add something different, not modify an existing item.

Comment: I see, thanks! If you would like to post an answer, I could accept it and we could close this question. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most naturally and commonly, that would be:

> 「あっ、**あと**、氷**も**入れていただけませんか？」

We also use 「それと」 as well.

Despite what you stated, 「それから」 is not a bad choice at all.  Native speakers use that, too.

You can say 「あとひとつ」, 「（それと/それから）もうひとつ」, etc. as well.

Comment: I see, thanks! I've encountered this situation quite a few times now without knowing what to say.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use also in this situation in English or in Japanese. If you wanted to add something to your order you could use 追加で or それに, but this situation is different.

If it's soon and they haven't left the table, you don't have to put anything in your ellipses. If they've started to leave, すみません, is fine. If some time has elapsed you might want to make it clear you're talking about your water by explicitly saying 水に.